# Which Python IDE has visual studio features?

Tags: python, visual-studio, ide, editor

I am searching for a Python IDE with visual studio features. After going through similar questions and reading reviews, I hardly see the following two features mentioned:

1. goto definition - e.g. go from the place where a method is called to its definition (perhaps the class is in another module).
2. find all references - something like "git grep method_name(" being done interactively inside the IDE.

Coding is so painful without them. Have you come across any python IDE with the above two features?

of course, the IDE need to have the essential features:

- code autocompletion
- integrated debugging
- basic IDE functions like syntax highlighting, error highlighting, smart indentation, bracket 
  matching, etc.

Comment: Smart indentation and bracket matching don't make much sense for Python.

Comment: Note that automatic code completion on Python is much less useful as you cannot do static code analysis for dynamic objects.

Comment: If smart indentation means auto-indenting as you type, it does make a lot of sense for Python.  Also Python IDEs can do pretty well w/ static analysis these days and some (Wing at least; not sure about the others) also use runtime data when available (like when the debugger is active or when working in a shell).

Answer (score 6):

Why not watch the great [PyCon 2011: Python IDEs Panel](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2011-python-ides-panel-4901374)!

You can use [Python Tools](http://pytools.codeplex.com/) which lets you program Python in Microsoft Visual Studio. [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), [Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide), or [WingWare](http://www.wingware.com/) should all fit the bill as well.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse with PyDev is outstanding. (It's also portable across platforms, as an added bonus. And free. And widely-used.)

Comment: If it's free (as in beer) it doesn't mean its "good", "outstanding" or "better".

Answer (score 1):

I've using [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) for all my Python projects for the past 8 months, and i definitely love it. I'd highly recommend it (even if it's not free, it's really cheap compared to its concurrents, and is far superior to them imho).

Comment: I tried Netbeans and PyCharm for python development... PyCharm is definitely better than Netbeans in all cases, i can say...

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found Wing, PyDev have the two features!

Answer (score 0):

support PyCharm , very good IDE for python!