# Is there an IDE with a GUI builder for Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Python IDE has visual studio features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964595/which-python-ide-has-visual-studio-features)
>   [Is there a good IDE for building GUI apps with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658028/is-there-a-good-ide-for-building-gui-apps-with-python)

I'm looking for some kind of Visual Basic like builder for Python. I'm not fussed about intellisense or highlighting, I can program Python. I'm looking for the GUI builder aspect, where I can drag a button onto the frame, and double click it and be able to edit it's code. Does such as thing exist?

Comment: There used to be [Boa Constructor](http://boa-constructor.sourceforge.net/), but that hasn't been maintained for a long time... which is too bad, because the name is just too cool to let it slip.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64971/what-is-the-best-wysiwyg-gui-editor-for-python

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a GUI using Qt, you may build it up with Qt Designer (a tool in the [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) IDE), then convert forms in Python code by using the `pyuic` compiler that comes with PyQt.